# Splitting out front matter from a Twig template with PCRE

Tags: php, regex, pcre, yaml-front-matter

Let's say I want to split the metadata from the Twig template

```
---
some metadata
multiple lines
---
Twig template
More data
```

I came up with `/\A---\R(.+?\R)?---\R(.*)\Z/s` which does it more or less but I am wondering whether it can become pathological in backtracking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex seems working well.

You may make it somewhat more efficient if you "unroll" the first lazy dot pattern like

```
/\A---\R(.*(?:\R(?!---\R).*)*\R)?---\R(?s)(.*)\Z/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TEHqo5/2). Note: no mofifiers are necessary, there is one inline `(?s)` modifier inside the pattern.

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `---\R` - a full `---` line with a linebreak
- `(.*(?:\R(?!---\R).*)*\R)?` - an optional Capturing group 1:

  - `.*` - the whole line
  - `(?:\R(?!---\R).*)*` - 0 or more repetitions of

    - `\R(?!---\R)` - a line break that is not followed with a `---` line followed with a linebreak
    - `.*` - the whole line
  - `\R` - a linebreak sequence
- `---\R` - a full `---` line with a linebreak
- `(?s)` - an inline DOTALL modifier making the dots to the right match line break chars
- `(.*)` Group 2: any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `\Z` - end of string.